# Error with $cordovaSQLite plugin on ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to query's on my db ... the problem is when I run my app, the screen is blank, I don't why. I read in `ionic.platform.ready()` and run perfect but when I want to use in a controller is wrong when the blank screen...

That's my code in `.ready()` function:

```
    var primera=[];
    var contador=0;
    var Citas = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "Citas.db", location: 'default'});
    var query= "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Codigo=?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(Citas, query, [0]).then(function(data){
      contador=data.rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
        var datos={
          codigo:'',
          telefono:'',
          password:'',
          status:''
        };
        datos.codigo = data.rows.item(i).codigo;
        datos.telefono = data.rows.item(i).telefono;
        datos.password= data.rows.item(i).password;
        datos.status= data.rows.item(i).status;
        primera.push(datos);
      }//fin del for
      //alert("SELECT activo de app"); 
    }, function(err){
    alert('Error al insertar datos primarios');
    });//fin del execute
```

That my code in my controller:

```
var Citas=window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'Citas.db', location: 'default'});
var query= "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE codigo=?";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(Citas, query, [0]).then(function(data){
  alert("entro en execute");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {

    var datos={
    codigo:'',
    telefono:'',
    password:'',
    status:''
    };
    datos.codigo = data.rows.item(i).codigo;
      datos.telefono = data.rows.item(i).telefono;
      datos.password= data.rows.item(i).password;
      datos.status= data.rows.item(i).status;
      $scope.sesion.push(datos);
  }//fin del for
  alert('Descarga Completada');
  if($scope.sesion[0].status=='activo'){
      $scope.tlf_login=$scope.sesion[0].telefono;
      $scope.pass_login=$scope.sesion[0].password;
      BuscarPersona();
    }
}, function(err){
    alert('Error al recuperar datos');
});//fin del execute
```

Comment: Can you do a 'cordova run android' and then go to 'chrome://inspect' on your chrome and report what you see in the console logs?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve that, What I do? well.. All this procedure convert a function and use a delay with $timeout before execute this function, so I guess that the problem was that as is a native function the sqlite so the device should be ready to use that.. In many word's:

```
$timeout(function() {
$scope.verificar_sesion();
}, 500);
```